# Spring Boot 2.0.0.M1: Where is the package org.springframework.boot.context.embed?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Spring Boot 1.5.3.RELEASE had several classes in `org.springframework.boot.context.embed` and also the subpackages `jetty`, `tomcat`, and `undertow`. However, `https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v2.0.0.M1/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context` doesn't contain the subdirectory `embed` anymore.

Where are classes like `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` gone?

Comment: If you manually pushed the project into github yourself. Those files and some other files will not be pushed. Examples like manifest.yml, target directory. Those classes that are missing can be found in .ignore.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Classes from  `org.springframework.boot.context.embedded` have been relocated to `org.springframework.boot.web`, and renamed. Check [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/67556ba8eaf22a352b03fe197a0c452f695835a6), for instance.

`TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` is now [`TomcatServletWebServerFactory`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/web/embedded/tomcat/TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java).