# EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer and ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer in Spring Boot 2

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We are using the next interfaces in Spring Boot 1.5.9, working without any problem: `ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer` and `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer`.

We have upgraded to Spring Boot 2 (2.0.0.M7), and these interfaces don't exist. We think they have been modified for other interfaces with the same purpose but we don't know what they are.

Could somebody help us in order to know how to modify this piece of code for having the same behaviour we had in Spring 1.5.9?

The code we have is the next:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() throws FileNotFoundException {

    final TomcatConnectorCustomizer customizer = new MyTomcatConnectionCustomizer(absoluteKeystoreFile,
            keystoreType, keystorePassword);
    return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {

        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
            if (container instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
                TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory containerFactory = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;
                containerFactory.addConnectorCustomizers(customizer);

                Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
                connector.setPort(port);
                containerFactory.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(connector);

            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot 2.0.0.M1: Where is the package org.springframework.boot.context.embed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44028875/spring-boot-2-0-0-m1-where-is-the-package-org-springframework-boot-context-embe)

Comment: Already addressed and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47554861/5873923) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44029322/5873923).

Comment: what did you want to customize here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to return an implementation of `ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory` as a bean, in your case `TomcatServletWebServerFactory`

```
@Bean
public ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory webServerFactory() {
    final TomcatConnectorCustomizer customizer = new MyTomcatConnectionCustomizer(absoluteKeystoreFile,
        keystoreType, keystorePassword);
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    factory.addConnectorCustomizers(connector -> {
        connector.setPort(port);
    }, customizer);
    return factory;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @shazin for your response. I have tested it and it compiles successfully. I can't test it because now I have a problem with the secure protocol (Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-443"]). I have to find out a solution for it first.