# org.springframework.boot.context.embedded does not exist - Gradle build Spring Boot Jetty

Tags: spring-boot, embedded-jetty

I am trying to replace Tomcat with Jetty, as my embedded servlet container. And then need to use EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() to configure redirecting requests at port 80 to port 443 (HTTPS). But I am stuck at the very beginning with these gradlew build errors:

> *RedirectHttpToHttpsOnJettyConfig.java:7: error: package org.springframework.boot.context.embedded does not exist*
>
> *import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer;*
>
> *RedirectHttpToHttpsOnJettyConfig.java:8: error: package org.springframework.boot.context.embedded does not exist*
>
> *import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer;*
>
> *RedirectHttpToHttpsOnJettyConfig.java:9: error: package org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty does not exist*
>
> *import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory;*
>
> *RedirectHttpToHttpsOnJettyConfig.java:10: error: package org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty does not exist*
>
> *import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyServerCustomizer;*
>
> *...*

Here's my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

ext['thymeleaf.version'] = '3.0.9.RELEASE'

war {
    baseName = 'reachout'
    version =  '0.0.2'
}

compileJava {
    options.warnings = true
    options.debug = true
    options.compilerArgs += ["-Xlint:deprecation"]
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
             exclude '**/RedirectHttpToHttpsOnTomcatConfig.java'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("com.h2database:h2")
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
```

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Duplicate. See

[Spring Boot 2.0.0.M1: Where is the package org.springframework.boot.context.embed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44028875/spring-boot-2-0-0-m1-where-is-the-package-org-springframework-boot-context-embe)

Here is the relevant spring commit

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/67556ba8eaf22a352b03fe197a0c452f695835a6

Comment: Thanks. This helped; build went through!